# Visual Studio 2017 - Moving dll out of bin folder

Tags: c#, sql, dll, visual-studio-2017

I'm just learning at the moment. I've copied a c# "Hello World" Script in to a visual studio project.

I then import the dll into my sql database with a query, and make it in to a stored procedure.

This works fine.

I wish to move the dll out of the \bin folder to a folder on the network drive, where i intend to keep any other dll files for use in my database.

When I do this I get an error on trying to create an asymmetrical key with the following script

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY CLRKey
    FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'R:\DataBases\DLLs\ClassLibrary1.dll'
```

Msg 15208, Level 16, State 45, Line 27
The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

The same code worked when the dll was still in the \bin folder. Even when I delete absolutely everything else and leave it as just a dll on its own in the \bin folder it still works. But as soon as I move the dll it stops working. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: System user that is running an sql engine should have permission for that folder

Comment: I'd already tried this, as i needed to do this with one of my other pieces of code and thought that it might be the problem. 

I just tried it again, putting it in to a folder which sql has permissions on. The sql user has modify, read & execute, list folder contents, read, write permissions on the folder in question. It still does not work.

Comment: If your code is working with `C:\Program Files\Something...` and it does not work with `R:\Databases\Something...` you realize it can only be permissions issue or server location can't see that R disk.. either way it's Windows Administration issue more likely than not.

Comment: Fixed. I had to either put the full network address "\\CHILFEN4\Master Order\DataBases\DLLs\HelloWorld.dll", or mount the network address as the R drive. Thank you for your suggestions.